# PHP pthreads: the lack of resource error

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

Just got PHP pthreads error

> pthreads has detected that the multihread could not be started, the system lacks the necessary resources or the system-imposed limit would be exceeded

and

> Cannot initialize zend_mm storage [win32]

in my script...

The PHP code looks like this:

```
class multihread extends Worker  {
    public $result;
    function __construct($e) {
        $this->e = $e;
    }
    public function run() {
        $this->result=file($this->e);
    }
}



$threads = 15;
do {
    for($i=1; $i<=$threads; $i++) {
        if(empty($thread[$i])){
            $e=generate_e($i);
            if($e==false){
                echo "Warning: no more job for e. exiting A"; exit;
            }
            echo "Starting new thread $i \n";
            $thread[$i] = new multihread($e);
            $thread[$i]->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
        }
        elseif($thread[$i]->isWorking()===false) {
            if($thread[$i]->result===false){
                echo "ERROR:Something wrong with thread $i, exit.";
                exit;
            }
            $thread[$i]->shutdown();
            $eval=generate_e($i);
            if($e==false){
                echo "Warning: no more job exiting B"; exit;
            }
            $thread[$i] = new multihread($e);
            $thread[$i]->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
        }
    }
    usleep(100);
}
while(1);
```

So, script open new thread, start this thread, then close thread with shutdown() and do it in the loop. It's worked like charm, but after 16000+ opened\closed threads got this error. Seems some resources stay locked? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One shall either [detach()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.detach.php) the thread before it ends, or call [join()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.join.php) on it to wait until it ended.

Missing the one or the other leads to the thread's resources **not** getting freed and though the system runs out of resources, as observed.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that script use `Worker` instead of `Thread`, and I don't know how to `detach` an `worker`.

Comment: `Worker` inherits the methods `join()` and `detach()` from `Thread`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php @user3742227